# Typescript Error when library doesn't have any downloadable types

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm

I am trying to use react-keydown library on my project, but I have the following error :

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-keydown'. '/home/path../node_modules/react-keydown/dist/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

Try `npm install @types/react-keydown` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'react-keydown';

The problem is that **react-keydown doesn't have any downloadable @types**, is there any way I can manually fix that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FIX :

1. Creating a react-keydowns.d.ts file to my src folder.
2. Adding `declare module 'react-keydown'`

Answer (score 1):

you can manually add `node_modules/@types/react-keydown/index.d.ts` which is include only `declare module 'react-keydown';`

Comment: Wouldn't add this to `node_modules`. The declaration file should be in the the project itself and make sure it is included in `tsconfig` file

Comment: I added this in my src folder, it solved the problem, but what do you mean by including it in tsconfig file ?